# How can I pick the photo from the device in Zebble for Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-zebble, zebble

I want to get the picture from the user in my application and for this reason, I use file picker which exists in Zebble UI components like this code:

In my page:

```
<FilePicker Id="MyFilePicker"></FilePicker>
```

I did find the code from this link 
http://zebble.net/docs/filepicker-class
But, I had a problem with this component, because I just want to pick some pictures from the device, not video or anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in your question I review the website and find this code, after that I tested it on my android device and I figure out this is the answer.

First, add this code to your page to show the file picker user interface

```
  <z-place inside="Body">

    <FilePicker Id="MyFilePicker"></FilePicker>

  </z-place>
```

Then, add below code to the page code behind to set the control just for picking the photos.

```
 public override async Task OnInitializing()
 {
        await base.OnInitializing();
        await InitializeComponents();

        MyFilePicker.Set(x => x.AllowOnly(MediaSource.PickPhoto, 
       MediaSource.TakePhoto));
 }
```